# Nodejs dynamic OG tags

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-opengraph

Using Express. Here's the route. It basically just passes the url params into a template that renders the OG tags.

```
router.get('/share/:redirectURL/:title/:description/:img', function (req, res) {

    var url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl; // points to this endpoint

    res.render('share', {
        url: url,
        title: decodeURIComponent(req.params.title),
        img: decodeURIComponent(req.params.img),
        description: decodeURIComponent(req.params.description),
        redirectURL: decodeURIComponent(req.params.redirectURL)
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

And here's the share template that it renders to.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(property="og:url", content="#{url}")
        meta(property="og:image", content="#{img}")
        meta(property="og:title", content="#{title}")
        meta(property="og:description", content="#{description}")
        meta(property="og:type", content="article")

    body
        script.
            location.replace("#{redirectURL}");
```

...and it works! But it only works LOCALLY. As soon as I upload to the server, things go awry.

works: `http://localhost/share/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com/Hear%20some%20music./http%3A%2F%2F201.23.456.789%2F%2Fassets%2Fimgs%2Ffavicons%2Ficon1024.png`

doesn't work: `http://123.45.678.910/share/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com/Hear%20some%20music./http%3A%2F%2F201.23.456.789%2F%2Fassets%2Fimgs%2Ffavicons%2Ficon1024.png`

Something upstream is partially decoding the url BEFORE it gets to the Express router. The result is this confused, useless thing.

`http://123.45.678.910/share/http:/google.com/Hear%20some%20music./http%3A%2F%2F201.23.456.789%2F%2Fassets%2Fimgs%2Ffavicons%2Ficon1024.png`

Answer (score 1):

Switched to query parameters and it works!